Can't find pertinent functions relating to page table functionality?
I've been playing around with how page tables work in Linux.
I notice, in particual, that function relating to "pte" do not exist within breaking them in gdb. Functions like "pte_alloc" are not found when trying to break them within gdb.
My Linux kernel is setup as x86 32bit, no 64bit.

pte_alloc is a kernel function.  Are you debugging the kernel?

yes i am. using qemu with gdb. using recent version of linux.

Have you looked at the source?  pte_alloc is a macro that calls __pte_alloc.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.11.7/source/include/linux/mm.h#L3012
